# Button click event is not reponding

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uibutton, vuforia, eaglview

I'm working with vuforia augmented Reality app. I'm displaying a button in EAGLView. But the button is not responding to click event. I have to get screenshot of what augmenting in top of overlay while ImageTarget is detect. After image recognize the overlay content and button is displaying on top of overlay. But while clicking the button it's not responding to user event

EAGLView.h:

```
 Display 3D object:

    @interface Object3D : NSObject {
        unsigned int numVertices;
        const float *vertices;
        const float *normals;
        const float *texCoords;

        unsigned int numIndices;
        const unsigned short *indices;

        Texture *texture;
    }

@interface ImageTargetsEAGLView : UIView <UIGLViewProtocol> {

 @private

 UIButton *photo;

 }

 @property (nonatomic) BOOL takePhotoFlag;
```

EAGLView.mm :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame appSession:(SampleApplicationSession *) app

 {

 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

 if (self) {

 takePhotoFlag = NO;

 [self DisplayPhotoButton];

 return self;

 }

 - (void)takePhoto

{

 NSLog(@"button pressed");

takePhotoFlag = YES;
}


- (void)DisplayPhotoButton

 {

 UIImage *closeButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];

 // UIImage *closeButtonTappedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_close_pressed.png"];

 CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(20,20,

 closeButtonImage.size.width,

 closeButtonImage.size.height);

 photo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

 photo.frame = aRect;

 [photo setImage:closeButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [photo addTarget:self action:@selector(takePhoto) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 [self  addSubview:photo];

 }



 - (BOOL)presentFramebuffer

 {


 if (takePhotoFlag)

 {

 [self glToUIImage];

 takePhotoFlag = NO;

 }

 }
```

Code for displaying overlay:

```
- (void)targetFound:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.targetOverlayView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"targetOverlayView" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

        Book *aBook = [notification object];
        [self.targetOverlayView setBook:aBook];
        [booksDelegate setLastScannedBook:aBook];

        [booksDelegate setOverlayLayer:self.targetOverlayView.layer];
        [self.view addSubview:self.targetOverlayView];
}
```

Comment: Is your button responding to touch?

Comment: It's not responding to touch..

Comment: check is there a invisible view above it?

Comment: TargetOverlayView is above on it. TargetOverlayView displaying content on camera overlay like top of view.

Comment: post some code how are you adding TargetOverlayView

Comment: check my edited code displaying image on overlay

Comment: Does i have to add my button from EAGLView to targetFound: method?

Comment: check if userInteractionEnabled is 'YES' for your view